# update a certain column in table A when table A email equals to table B email

Tags: mysql, sql

Table B have the following column: `Email Address`
and Table A have the following column: `email`

How do I update Table A `newsletter` to = 0 where A.`Email Address` = B.`email`?

I've tried with the following which seems to fail:

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET TableA.newsletter = 0
FROM TableB, TableA
WHERE TableA.email = TableB.Email Address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the query should look like while updating data joining 2 tables with a key

```
update 
TableA t1
inner join TableB t2 on t2.`Email Address` = t1.email
set t1.newsletter = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing backticks for the TableB.Email Address column, anytime you have special characters or spaces you will need to add backticks for columns\tablenames\schemas.

```
UPDATE
TableA A, TableB B
SET A.newsletter = 0
WHERE A.email = B.`Email Address`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sub query

```
UPDATE TableA ta
SET TableA.newsletter = 0
WHERE `Email Address` IN
(SELECT email FROM TableB WHERE email = ta.`Email Address`)
```